# How can I cast shadow from a transparent material?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to cast shadow from a transparent material.
Here my simple code on https://glitch.com/edit/#!/elite-invented-television
As you can see the shadow of my foliage is bad (I got the shadow of the plane), how can I improve this rendering?

[edit1]
A solution has been found (Thanks Piotr Adam ;), have a look to the "edited" glitch (the first one)...
[/edit1]

[edit2]
Well, I try now to apply the previous trick on a chromakey material without success. Here an other glitch : https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-chromakey
Any idea?
[/edit2]

Comment: I assume you want to get the shadow of only not transparent part - and not the entire plane? I don't know if this is possible without some THREE js magic. Maybe this will help? https://discourse.threejs.org/t/shadows-not-taking-alpha-mask-into-account/11127/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Piotr Kolecki mentioned in his comment, one way would be to use a [custom depth material](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=MeshDepthMaterial#api/en/materials/MeshDepthMaterial).

Adapting it into an `a-frame` component would be simple, as You could re-use the texture loaded by the material:

```
// provided all is loaded:
const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
var customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial( {
  depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,
  map: mesh.material.map
  alphaTest: 0.5
});
mesh.customDepthMaterial = this.customDepthMaterial;
```

---

A simple component seemed neat, so you can use [this one](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/depth-material/) ([source](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/tree/master/aframe/depth-material)) that I did just for testing. It works with `.png` textures, and lottie animations.

You can use it simply by adding a `depth-material` component to your plane:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/depth-material/depth-material.js"></script>
<a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
  <a-assets>
    <img id="foliage" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/9418ac7b-9d22-4434-9511-18282652475b%2Ffoliage.png?v=1620389632977">
  </a-assets>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="8" height="8" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
  <a-plane position="0 1 -1.5" material="src: #foliage; side: double; transparent: true" 
           shadow depth-material>
  </a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: @Brun0oO if you don't have further questions feel free to mark the answer :)

Comment: Now, If I try to apply this component on a material with a chromakey effect, the depth-material trick is not applied, any idea?. Here my example code : https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-chromakey

Comment: @Brun0oO it's not working because of a couple of reasons - 1) the `chroma-key` component hides the texture, so it cannot be accessed with `material.map`. 2) Even if you grab the video texture, it has the green channel - no parts are transparent. What you see is the final resul of the shader, not a prepared texture.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to invert the colors on the video, so that the dancer would be green (and use it as a alphaMap) 
[glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-67436423?path=index.html%3A59%3A49). A harder solution, would be to render the dancer in a 
[WebGLRenderTarget](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget) and use it as the texture. 
Another one would be to modify the chroma-key shader to include light / shadows info. But that would require some shader knowledge. 
I can try to prepare an example with the WebGLRenderTarget later.